# Merge multiple 3D files with AutoDesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I can make the files (.step) to show on the Forge Viewer, giving each file coordinates and rotation (x, y, z) but of course i can't download the final result.

Is there a way to create the file before the Viewer?

For example i have 2 3D files, one with an "A" and the other with a "B".
If i load in the Viewer file "A" (X:0,Y:0,Z:0) and "B" (X:5,Y:0,Z:0) with these coordinates i can view my final 3D like this "AB", but i can't download the final result from the viewer.

There is a way to create a new file from the AutoDesk API from a list of files?

Answer (score 0):

The Forge Viewer is read-only, this is not an editor. In a viewer session you can do anything you want like merging multiple sources, moving objects around, etc... but remember this is a Viewer and all changes you make are transient changes.

If you want to combine STEP files together into a single file, you can either edit the step files and merge them manually in a text editor. Or you can use Forge Design Automation for Inventor to import, assemble the scene, and export the result. A good scenario would be to use the Viewer to position all the step sources where you want them, and launch Design Automation to create the resulting step file based on that information. There is couple of examples on the [Autodesk Forge Github repo](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/) which do similar scenario.

Comment: Can you link me the repo where they do this? i can't understand how to use the Design Automation to create and import files.Thanks.